# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'Symbol(dartx._get)') FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, flutterwebviewplugin

I converted an existing flutter app to support web, I am trying to get data to display as list and this error occurred.

full code:

class InformationPage extends StatefulWidget {

final Map<String, List> newsData;

InformationPage({Key key, this.newsData}) : super(key: key);

@override

_InformationPageState createState() => _InformationPageState();

}

class _InformationPageState extends State

```
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
```

ScrollController _scrollController;

TabController _tabController;

int currentIndex = 0;

String firstName = '', lastName = '', email = '';

Map<String, List> _newsData = Map<String, List>();

UserDetailsResponse _userDetailsResponse;

final AsyncMemoizer _profileAsync = AsyncMemoizer();

Pandora _pandora = Pandora();

@override

void initState() {

```
super.initState();

getProfileInformation();

_scrollController = ScrollController();

_tabController = TabController(length: categories.length, vsync: this);

_tabController.addListener(_smoothScrollToTop);

setState(() {

  _newsData = Map.from(widget.newsData);

});
```

}

_smoothScrollToTop() {

```
if (_scrollController.hasClients)

  _scrollController.animateTo(

    0,

    duration: Duration(microseconds: 300),

    curve: Curves.ease,

  );
```

}

void changePage(int index) {

```
setState(() {

  currentIndex = index;

});
```

}

@override

void dispose() {

```
_tabController.dispose();

_scrollController.dispose();

super.dispose();
```

}

Widget _showLoader() {

```
return Padding(

    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 40),

    child: SingleChildScrollView(

      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),

      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,

      child: Column(

        children: [

          SizedBox(

            height: 25,

          ),

          LoaderTileLarge(),

          SizedBox(

            height: 16,

          ),

          LoaderTileLarge(),

          SizedBox(

            height: 16,

          ),

          LoaderTileLarge(),

          SizedBox(

            height: 16,

          ),

          LoaderTileLarge(),

          SizedBox(


            height: 16,

          ),

          LoaderTileLarge(),

          SizedBox(

            height: 16,

          ),

          LoaderTileLarge(),

          SizedBox(

            height: 16,

          ),

          LoaderTileLarge(),

        ],

      ),

    )
```

);

}

@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

```
return Container(

  child: FutureBuilder(

      builder: (context, snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none &&

                snapshot.hasData == null ||

            snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {

          return _showLoader();

        }

        return Stack(

          children: [

            Container(

              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,

              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,

              color: Colors.white,

            ),

            NestedScrollView(

                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),

                controller: _scrollController,

                headerSliverBuilder: (context, value) {

                  return [

                    SliverToBoxAdapter(

                      child: Column(

                        children: [

                          AppBar(

                            elevation: 0.1,

                            backgroundColor: AppColors.whiteColor,

                            leadingWidth: 0.0,

                            leading: Container(),

                            title: Text('News',

                                overflow: TextOverflow.fade,

                                style: TextStyle(

                                    color: Colors.black,

                                    fontSize: 23.0,

                                    fontFamily: 'semibold',

                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
```

)
),

```
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(

                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(

                                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),

                                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(20)),

                            ),

                          ),

                          Container(

                            height: 10,

                          )

                        ],

                      ),

                    ),

                    SliverToBoxAdapter(

                      child: Container(

                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),

                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,

                        child: TabBar(

                            labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),

                            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,

                            controller: _tabController,

                            isScrollable: true,

                            indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(

                                borderSide:

                                    BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),

                            labelColor: Colors.black,

                            labelStyle: TextStyle(

                                color: Colors.black,

                                fontSize: 19.0,

                                fontFamily: 'semibold',

                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),

                            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black45,

                            unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(

                                color: Colors.black,

                                fontSize: 18.0,

                                fontFamily: 'regular',

                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),

                            tabs: List.generate(categories.length,

                                (index) => Text(categories[index].name)
```

)
),

```
                      ),

                    ),

                  ];

                },

                body: Container(

                  child: TabBarView(

                      controller: _tabController,

                      children: List.generate(categories.length, (index) {

                        if (categories == null ||

                            categories[index] == null ||

                            categories[index].imageUrl == null) {

                          return SizedBox.shrink();

                        }

                        var key = categories[index].imageUrl.toString();

                        return ListView.separated(

                          itemCount: 10,

                          separatorBuilder: (context, index) {

                            return Divider(

                              color: AppColors.dividerColor,

                              height: 1,

                            );

                          },

                          shrinkWrap: true,

                          itemBuilder: (context, i) {

                            return DashboardFeedCard(

                                title: _newsData[key][i]['title']["\$t"],

                                subtitle: _pandora

                                    .removeAllHtmlTags(_newsData[key][i]

                                        ['description']["\$t"])

                                    .replaceAll('&nbsp;', ' '),

                                time: _newsData[key][i]['pubDate']["\$t"],

                                source: _newsData[key][i]['source']["\$t"],

                                url: _newsData[key][i]['link']["\$t"]);

                          },

                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),

                        );

                      })),

                ))

          ],

        );

      },

      future: getProfileInformation()),

);
```

}

Future getProfileInformation() async {

```
return this._profileAsync.runOnce(() async {

  _userDetailsResponse = await getUserDetails();

  if (_userDetailsResponse != null) {

    Session.userDetailsResponse = _userDetailsResponse;

    setState(() {

      firstName = _userDetailsResponse.user.firstName;

      email = _userDetailsResponse.user.email;

    });

  }

  return _userDetailsResponse;

});
```

}
}

I have tried checking my firebase connection and initialization and everything seems ok.

The stack error keep taking me to this particular widget DashboardFeedCard